# Syntax Error that I can't find

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm pulling my hairs here...

```
import os
import random
MAC = (0,0,":",0,0,":")
chars = ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e')
a = 5
while (a <= 17):
  if a == 6 | a == 9 | a == 12 | a == 15:
    MAC.append(":")
  else:
    MAC.append(chars(random.randomint(0,15))

  a += 1
print MAC
```

What am I doing wrong?! The indentation is correct, just as the example shows. Any help is welcomed.
**EDIT:** OH CRAP, forgot to show what the error is..

> File "macchanger.py", line 12
>       a += 1
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the logical or (`or`) and not the bitwise or (`|`).

Chars is not a function, but an array. Use array subscripts to get at values. (i.e. `chars[rand]` and not `chars(rand)`.

You're missing a parenthesis after the append random char line.

You also can't append to tuples, need to make `MAC` a list.

The `random` module also has no 'randomint' function. You're looking for `randint`.

---

**edit**: This can also replace your entire function if you're looking to use Python's generators:

```
MAC = ':'.join(['%02x'%c for c in [0, 0]+[random.randint(0,255) for d in range(4)]])
```

Comment: Is `||` even valid Python syntax?  Logical or is `or`.  And `chars` here is a tuple.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me how does your one line function works? I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: Sure, read up on how Python's list comprehension works: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @yan: You can even lose the outermost `[` `]`, turning a list comprehension into a generator expression.

Comment: Yup, but I worked on that expression for a minute and as soon as i had the array, just wrapped it in the str.join(), leaving them in. You're right though :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import os
import random

def makeMAC(pre=None):
    pre = [int(i) for i in pre] if pre else []
    for byte in range(len(pre), 6):
        pre.append(random.randint(0,255))
    return ':'.join('%02x'%(i) for i in pre)

print makeMAC([0,0])
```

returns

```
00:00:cd:c1:7d:c0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. missing closing parenthese in

   MAC.append(chars(random.randomint(0,15))
2. MAC needs to be list since you're appending, tuples are immutable
3. random.randint (and not random.randomint)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- The one the compiler tells you about - mismatches parens at the line above (as always, the exact error message would have helped)
- You're using `|` (the bitwise or) when you want `or` (the logical or). Note that you can do this check better, by using `a in <tuple of values>`.
- You can't `.append` to a tuple (or otherwise mutate it), use a list.
- You should simply use `for a in range(5, 18)` instead of counting manually in a while loop.
- You're *calling* the `chars` tuples - indexing uses square backets (`chars[...]`). Note that you just use `random.choice`.